# Excel VBA not displaying 5 precision decimal

Tags: excel, vba, decimal, precision

```
Dim StrIntVar1 As String

StrIntVar1 = "123456780123.12345"
StrIntVar1 = Format(StrMA663UnitCstAmt, "###0.00000")

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Main_Sheet).Cells(1, 1).Value = StrIntVar1
```

The Cell Displays = `1234567890123.12`

The Cell should be displaying `123456780123.12345`

Comment: Excel has a 15 digit floating point precision. This effectively rounds off your number to 15 significant digits. see [About calculation in workbooks](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-calculation-in-workbooks-HP005198322.aspx) for more information.

Comment: What is **StrMA663UnitCstAmt**?

Comment: If you're not going to use it in calculation and just want to display the numbers correctly, enter it as text by using a *Prefix Character* e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Main_Sheet).Cells(1, 1).Value = "'" & StrIntVar1`